# AutoMapping Array to a List

Tags: c#, arrays, collections, automapper

```
class A
{
  public List<string> list;
}

class B
{
  public string[] array;
}
```

How would you map this?

I've tried

```
CreateMap<A,B>();
```

That doesn't work

Comment: `b.array = a.list.ToArray()` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your first issue is going to be that the class members don't match. If they did, I'd imagine that this would work. If not, you just have to specify your mapping rather than letting Automapper infer it:

```
CreateMap<A,B>()
    .ForMember(d => d.array, opts => opts.MapFrom(s => s.list.ToArray());
```

Comment: The collection is  not a string but a NameValueCollection for two different name spaces so I'm assuming those need to be mapped too. Any ideas there?

Comment: Yes, it's because the names don't match, it has nothing to do with arrays/lists. @Proximo you might want to update your question to include the actual collection types.

Comment: I was going to but I figured out how to map the different internal collections individually. This answer saved the day.

Answer (score 0):

For a shortcut, a vb.net version

```
CreateMap(Of A, B)().ForMember(Function(d) d.array, Sub(opts) opts.MapFrom(Function(s) s.list.ToArray()))
```