# C# AutoMapper Array to a List

Tags: c#, automapper

I have read [AutoMapping Array to a List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24539606/automapping-array-to-a-list) but this is actually List to Array and I do want Array to List. Here is my code:

```
using AutoMapper;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace PocArrayListMap
{
    class Destination
    {
        public List<string> list = new List<string>();
    }

    class Origin
    {
        public string[] array;
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<Origin, Destination>().ForMember(e => e.list, opts => opts.MapFrom(s => s.array.ToList())));

            var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<Origin, Destination>());
            config.AssertConfigurationIsValid(); // Exception here

            var o = new Origin() { array = new string[] { "one", "two", "three" } };

            var d = Mapper.Map<Destination>(o);

            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", d.list));
        }
    }
}
```

and here is the exception message:

> Origin -> Destination (Destination member list)
>
> PocArrayListMap.Origin -> PocArrayListMap.Destination (Destination member list)
>
> Unmapped properties:
>
> list

Using the latest nuget of Automapper (6.2.2) and .Net 4.6.2 Not that it is platform or version related.

**edit** as said here, https://stackoverflow.com/a/5591125/169714 automapper should do list and array stuff automatically. But I keep getting unmapped properties. Even when I have the `ForMember` method.

Comment: Why don't you configure the member mapping in `new MapperConfiguration` instead of calling `Mapper.Initialize`. Do you expect the initialize to have any effect on your newly created configuration?

Comment: omg, i was asleep. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried this code (with Automapper 6.2.2) and it's working on my side:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<Origin, Destination>().ForMember(e => e.list, opts => opts.MapFrom(s => s.array.ToList())));
        Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();

        Origin o = new Origin {array = new[] {"one", "two", "three"}};
        Destination d = Mapper.Map<Destination>(o);

        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", d.list));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your list containing any items? Because I can't see if you assign a value to it, from my view your list is empty...

In [this](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/1386) thread, one of the comments was: "Now that 5.0.1 had come out I had to change this to CreateMap(MemberList.None) otherwise I would get the error".

Hope I helped!